# How to import something globally in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing an App using React Native and Firebase. So, I created a separate `js` file to store `config` of `firebase database` and then I imported that `config` file into my `screen` files when I need to connect with `firebase database`.

So, I have to import that `config` file into each and every `screen` file which I need connect with my `firebase database`.

I want to know that, is it possible to import that `config` file `globally`?

I mean, I create a separate `config` file, then `import` it only once into a particular `js` file (Just for an example, let's think, `import` it only once into the `App.js` file) and then, use it in my `screen` files whenever I need to connect with my `firebase database`. But in this case, is it possible to use that `config` file without importing it into each and every `screen` file?

Hope you will understand what I want to do.

Comment: You need to import the file ,where you wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just import the file in your main screen/ app entry point.

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';


const config = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "DOMAIN",
  databaseURL: "DB_URL",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "MSG_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID"
};
app.initializeApp(config);

module.Store = {

  Firebase() {
    return app;
  },
}


if (global) {
  global.Store = module.Store;
}
```

In your main screen

```
import './Global';
```

all the functions in Global will be available to all screens.

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/global-variable-in-react-native)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain your answer? My firebase config file name is `firebase.config.js'. How to put your logic for that case?

Comment: how are you currently exporting it?you can just return the config from one of the functions

Comment: currently, I exported from the `firebase.config.js` and import it into the `screen` file like this... `import firebaseConfig from '../path/to/config/file/firebase.config'`